# Do I need to create seperate OSGi bundles for each jar

Tags: maven, log4j, osgi, log4j2, osgi-bundle

I want to create an OSGi bundle for log4j2. I need to use some additional jars along with log4j2 such as log4j2-jcl, log4j2-jul, log4j2-web etc. I want to clarify some confusions listed below about this.
However this is not specific to log4j2 I'm asking this as a general procedure.

1. Do I need to create separate OSGi bundles for each jar or can I use one bundle for all the jars? (What is the best practice)
2. How can I know whether OSGi bundles are already available for these jars ? (So that I don't need to re create bundles, can use existing ones)

I'm quite new to OSGi so can anyone please clarify these things no need to specific for log4j2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Do I need to create separate OSGi bundles for each jar or can I use one bundle for all the jars? (What is the best practice)

I recommend to create one bundle per JAR, if possible. This gives you the greatest flexibility and makes sure that each JAR is properly designed.

> 2. How can I know whether OSGi bundles are already available for these jars ? (So that I don't need to re create bundles, can use
>      existing ones)

Just have a look at the Manifest file.

If it contains the OSGi Metadata -> it's a OSGi bundle.

If it doesn't contain the OSGi Metadata -> it's not a OSGi bundle.

I think the Log4J JARs already provide the OSGi Metadata (-> they are already bundles), but I haven't double-checked.

Comment: Puce, thanks for the answer that is really helpful. I checked MANIFEST.MF inside META-INF of log4j2 jars. They provide OSGi Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

just a recommendation.
before you do any bundle, check if it exists.
https://jpm4j.org/#!/search?q=log4j2

also, I recommend slf4j

Comment: jpm4j.org is great for getting informations about the bundle. 
But take care, you find there also libraries which are not yet an OSGi bundle.